# How to query Facebook comments plugin comments information using C#? (followup)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, c#-4.0, facebook-comments

This is a followup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246150/how-to-query-facebook-comments-plugin-comments-information-using-c).

Using the following code:

```
// this is to manually initiate web fetch (as opposed to Facebook client)
public static String GetUrlText(String url)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.UserAgent = DefaultUserAgent;

    if (UseProxyHost)
    {
        request.Proxy = Proxy;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    }

    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        Debug.Assert(responseStream != null, "responseStream != null");
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            string ret = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return ret;
        }
    }
}


// initialization
string oauthUrl = $"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id={appId}&client_secret={appSecret}";
string accessToken = client.DownloadString(oauthUrl).Split('=')[1];
var fbClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

var pageUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments");   
var getUrl = $"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?fields=og_object{{comments}}&id={pageUrl}&access_token={accessToken}";

var urlText = GetUrlText(getUrl); 
// getUrl can skip accessToken    
var fbComments = fbClient.Get(getUrl);
```

Both `urlText` and `fbComments` will receive JSON content shown below.

I can get correct results within Google Chrome (copy-paste of `pageUrl`), but I receive a 400 error within IE11 and within C# code, with the following content:

```
{
   "og_object": {
      "id": "246649445486535"
   },
   "id": "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments"
}
```

**Question:** how to properly request the data, so that it works both on IE11 and in C#?

Comment: Why are you using HttpUtility.UrlDecode on the URL? It gets put into another URL as a parameter value, so it needs to be _encoded_. And when you make that request directly via the browser address bar, you of course need to append the access token as an additional parameter.

Comment: @CBroe - yes, I have fixed it, but the result is the same. I have also tested using `HttpWebRequest`, but I get the same request. I have also tested the URL (www.redirect-checker.org) to see if they use some redirect trick, but it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?fields=og_object{comments}&id=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2Fcomments&access_token=…` works fine, once you append a valid access token at the end.

Comment: @CBroe - yes, it also works for me, but only in Google Chrome and Firefox. Something is fishy (maybe it's related to corporate security/proxy configuration) preventing me to obtain data both in Internet Explorer 11 and C#. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it was not working. My requests require the following header:

```
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ro;q=0.6
```

The whole request construction code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
// can be omitted (included to look like a real browser)
request.UserAgent = DefaultUserAgent;
// required
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,ro;q=0.6");
```